# AST rewrite rule for OR lexer expressions

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have the following ANTLR rule:

```
procedure
 : ('int' | 'char') IDENT '(' args ')' body -> ^(PROCEDURE IDENT (args)* body)
 ;
```

I want to capture the `('int' | 'char')` portion in the AST. As you can see, on the right hand side it doesn't appear, but I'm not sure how to have the chosen `'int'` or `'char'` appear in the AST. I'd like the `'int'` or '`char'` portion to be in the tree under the `PROCEDURE` root but *before* the `IDENT`.

Comment: Note that you have `args*` inside your rewrite rule, but `args` in the parser rule. You probably want to remove the `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can label the pair, and then reference the label in the rewrite:

```
procedure
    : primType=('int' | 'char') IDENT '(' args ')' body
      -> ^(PROCEDURE $primType IDENT args body)
    ;
```